# Visualizing the exactness of two-dimensional differentials

Tags: differential, vector-fields

One of the very first notions one encounters when introduced to total differentials $\text{d}f$ is the notion of *exactness*, that is the property of $f(x,y)$ that in $$\text{d}f=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\text{d}x + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\text{d}y$$ we have
$$
\tag{$\spadesuit$}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right).
$$
Now we can interpret in the above $\text{d}f$ as a scalar product of the gradient $\vec{\nabla}f$ with $\text{d}\vec{r}=(\text{d}x,\text{d}y)$ and so the integrability condition $(\spadesuit)$ reads as an equality of the directional derivatives of the gradient along the $x$ and $y$ axes.

This means if we were to plot the gradient of $f$ as a vector field, it should be symmetric under reflections along the diagonal $x=y$. These reflections are displayed by red lines in the following.

As an example, take $\text{d}f=\cos(x)\sin(y)\text{d}x-\sin(x)\cos(y)\text{d}y$, which is not exact:
[image]

Compare with $\text{d}f=\sin(x)\cos(y)\text{d}x+\cos(x)\sin(y)\text{d}y$, which is exact:[image]

Now, assuming the above interpretation is correct, is there a nice way to see in the vector field plot the following two things:

- Whether $\oint_C \text{d}f$ will be $=0$ in the exact and $\neq0$ in the inexact case? So, is it possible to gain a hint as to the exactness of a given $\text{d}f$ from the visualization alone?${}^{[1]}$
- How an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ should look like, so that
  ($\spadesuit$) holds for $\mu\cdot \text{d}f$ if it doesn't for $\text{d}f$?

---

<sub>${}^{[1]}:$ Apart from those cases where $\oint_C \text{d}f \neq 0$ even for exact differentials, where because of terms like $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ we have to exclude certain points, which lead to singularities that change the closed loop integral when integrated around them.</sub>

Comment: If you're going to have exactness then there will need to be cancellation in line integrals around closed loops. Thus your field should sometimes be aligned with the path of a closed loop and other times anti-aligned. In your second figure, this happens: depending on where the loop is and the orientation, the horizontal parts are aligned/anti-aligned while the vertical parts are anti-aligned/aligned. In the first figure they are always one or the other. Of course just seeing cancellation does not guarantee exactness because you need *exact* cancellation.

Comment: Re the footnote: By the F.T.C. for line integrals we always have $\oint_C \omega = 0$ for any exact $1$-form $\omega = df$. This claim *can* fail, however, for merely *closed* $1$-forms $\omega$, at least when $C$ is not null-homotopic (in the domain of $\omega$).

Comment: @Ian Ah, that is of course a great insight, I'll keep that one in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement

> Now we can interpret in the above $\text{d}f$ as a scalar product of
>   the gradient $\vec{\nabla}f$ with
>   $\text{d}\vec{r}=(\text{d}x,\text{d}y)$ and so the integrability
>   condition $(\spadesuit)$ reads as an equality of the directional
>   derivatives of the gradient along the $x$ and $y$ axes.

and the associated picture with the red diagonal line, suggests that the exactness of a differential is dependent only on its values at or near the diagonal, which is completely untrue(*). I think you need to rethink that interpretation.

(*) Brief explanation: suppose that $\omega$ is everywhere inexact. Multiply $\omega$ by $f$, where $f$ is zero on a unit-width strip along the diagonal $x = y$, and $1$ outside a two-unit-wide strip along the diagonal. Then $f\omega$ will have zero gradient along the diagonal, hence appear "exact" by your criterion, but outside that wide strip, $f\omega = \omega$, and hence is inexact.

Comment: I think "symmetric along" was simply meant to be "symmetric about".

Comment: Well...as you might guess, that's no better, for if $\omega$ is inexact, it's pretty easy for $\eta = \omega(x, y) + \omega(y, x)$ to also be inexact, but it's symmetric about the line $x = y$. Indeed, $\omega(x, y) = 2xy ~dx$ is already inexact, but also symmetric.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the type of symmetry meant is not clear. It seems to me that the intended meaning is something like $M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = N(y,x) dx + M(y,x) dy$ (i.e. fully exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ does not change the form). This achieves the point but now it is both stronger than the partial derivative equality and no easier to check.

Comment: You may be right, but at some point my mind-reading skills fail me. What you've written requires that $M(x, y) = N(y, x)$, however, and not even standard exact 1-forms like $3yx^2 dx + x^3 dy$ satisfy that. Anyhow, since exactness/inexactness is clearly local, it seems likely that a global constraint like this won't really be all that informative.

Comment: Thanks you for your input - I'll give the symmetry property more thought then. By "symmetric along the diagonal" I actually meant "symmetric under reflections along the diagonal", I've edited that part in.